# What is the neatest way to run power to Somfy motorized window blinds?

Tags: electrical, windows, blinds

I have several Somfy RTS motorized window blinds installed. Right now they just have electric cables attached to them that could be tacked to the wall, but I'd rather have the cabling completely hidden. What is the best way to achieve this?

Could their power cabling be run through the wall and connected to the nearest power outlet, behind the scenes? I'd rather not have the power plug visible at all.

Here are a couple of photos of the setup:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rOeeL1b.jpg]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/HkWPe9C.jpg]

Comment: I'd love to help but I have to say their web site SUCKS! I cannot find an installation manual, and I'm pretty damn good at this internet thing. :/

Comment: OK, I found the section. Man, they do keep it hidden. Do you have a model number?

Comment: This Old House just had motorized blinds that had a battery with a solar recharge, no wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the best way to solve this was to request replacement Somfy motors with longer cords. The factory can supply them at any length, and they arrived within a week.

I have now had them installed and there was no junction box needed, since there is no join in the cable behind the wall. There is now no visible cable whatsoever.

I hope this is helpful to others who run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like this motorized shade it looks like you have to bring the cord into a box. From there you can hide all the wiring. You CANNOT bury that cord from the motor.

You can use a flush box with a grommet or strain relief in the cover.

[Installation manual](https://www.somfypro.com/somfy-corporate-search-portlet/somfydownload?path=%2Fdata%2Fnam%2Fdocuments%2FLS40_Motor_Installation_Instructions.pdf&t=ipwscByJ1dbcKuA%2Bp0zI55qimjaa3liqxiJ1b27L79sOVFPci9gtfwyKk7x1JaFMOoSlYzky8UxEpfvobx6p4VfKMh0V9mub&filename=LS40_Motor_Installation_Instructions.pdf)

Comment: That looks like the correct model, the LS40. Well discovered!

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, could you please explain what you mean about bringing the cord "into a box"? And also what a flush box is. Are these things I should purchase for each blind before having an electrician wire them in?

Comment: In case it's helpful, I do not need to connect the motors to a control switch - they operate via the RF remote control. They only need power connecting.

Comment: If you're having an electrician doing this work he'll have everything he needs.

Answer (score 1):

The way we installed them incredibly clean was the have the blinds mounted on the wall above the window alcove (not inside the cove as you did). The outlet is generally in line with where the blinds are and their "closed" state leaves them open enough to cover the outlets.